# How can I send out email updates from a private Blogger blog when adding new posts?

Tags: email, notifications, blogger, google-groups

I am setting up a blog using Blogger that needs to remain private.  I understand that a private blog cannot have an RSS feed or use feedburner for email notifications.

I am wondering what other options I have for users to receive an email notification of new posts on the blog.  I found a site suggesting that I could set up a Google group and use the email address for the group to send posts out to users, but I tried this and no email was sent out, i.e. I added the email address for the Google group to Settings/Mobile and Email/Email Posts to in Blogger, but the members of the Google group didn't receive an email.

I am wondering if there are other options?

Answer (score 1):

1.Sign in to Blogger

2.Click on your Blog Name

3.Click on `Settings`

4.Click on `Mobile and Email`

5.On the bottom click on `Add`,where it says `Email posts to`

6.Type the Email Address

7.On the top left,click on "Save Settings"

8.Create a new post and it shall take less than 48 hours for the email alert

Comment: Thanks, this works a charm, although it won't email more than 10 people at a time, which is a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group in Google and let anywone post to it (but not to read).

Then configure Blogger to send email message to this group.

In this way you can add more than 10 users (blogger limit)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?